# How to execute HLSL from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hlsl, compute-shader

So I'm writing a C# program in Visual Studio 2019 Community, however for some operations I'd want it to run on the GPU instead of the CPU.
I have a little experience with HLSL from having wrote for example some compute shaders for some Unity projects, however I have not really been able to find (through Google) any way of executing HLSL code from a C# program outside of using Unity.

Assuming my understanding of the term Kernel is correct (with how it's used in Unity for running compute shaders), I'd want to specifically:
1: from the CPU write some data to a buffer of a kernel of a shader,
2: run the kernel a certain amount of times, and
3: have the CPU read some buffers from the kernel.

To give an example of what I'd want, here is how I could get C# code to run a HLSL kernel with UnityEngine:
(For the example: in C# it generates some random numbers from -1 to 1, and then in the shader multiplies each entry by 4)
**C#**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    ComputeBuffer buffer;
    public ComputeShader shader; //Has been set to reference the shader in Unity

    void Start ()
    {
        //Create array of random values from -1 to 1
        int[] v = new int[4 * 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
        {
            v[i] = Random.Range(-1, 2);
        }
        //Create buffer
        buffer = new ComputeBuffer(v.Length, sizeof(int));
        shader.SetBuffer(0, "Result", buffer);
        //Set values of buffer to random values
        buffer.SetData(v);
        //Execute the shader
        shader.Dispatch(0, 4 / 2, 4 / 2, 1);
        //Get values of buffer
        buffer.GetData(v);
        //Dispose buffer
        buffer.Dispose();
        //Print values
        for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i += 4)
        {
            print(v[i + 0] + "," + v[i + 1] + "," + v[i + 2] + "," + v[i + 3]);
        }
    }
}
```

**HLSL**

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWStructuredBuffer<int> Result;

[numthreads(2,2,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    Result[id.x + id.y * 4] = 4 * Result[id.x + id.y * 4];
}
```

**Printed:**

> -4, 4, -4, 0
> 0, 4, 0, 0
> -4, -4, -4, 4
> 4, 0, 4, 4

**Edit: Things I've tried:**
2 weeks later and while no one have answered this questions, I have been looking for solutions. Still searching, but want to update this with some of the ways I've seen so far:
(Note that I haven't looked the most into some of these for example because they appear to not be what I am looking for)

- Microsoft seems to have an [official how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-compute-create) on compiling Compute Shaders, however it is for C++. If I am correct in this, one could probably use it to create a DLL to use in C#. Main problem I have with this method though, is that it requires knowledge of C++ which I don't have. I do plan on checking it out though.
- [Compute Sharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ComputeSharp/) is a NuGet package that claims to be able to take C# code, convert it to HLSL code, and run it on the GPU. This seems however to not quite be what I want, as it does not take HLSL code, but C# code. Decided to check it out anyways, as it is a pretty minor negative, however trying to install the latest version on NuGet (1.3.1), which is also the latest stable version, gave the error "Could not install package [...]. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets [.NetFramework version 4.7.2], but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. [...]".
  I therefor decided to check other methods first.
- [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) seems to be a NuGet package that lets you work with HLSL code in your C# .NET project. Using SharpDX.Direct3D11, you can even create Compute Shaders. Seems exactly like what I want, which is why I've looked more into this one than the others. I've just experienced one big problem with this one: SharpDX seems to have very little in the form of tutorials or explanations on how to use it. Using what Google Translate says is a [Japanese example of a Compute Shader using SharpDX](https://gist.github.com/oguna/624969e732a868ec17f05694012c1b63) as a blueprint, I was able to get something working. The problem with what I was able to make is that 1) there are parts I don't understand at all what they do, just that it does not work without them, and 2) making what seems like completely acceptable changes, like having a second buffer, can break it in weird ways. Plus seemingly having to reference structured buffers through their position in the compiled shader (not their position pre-compiled), seems really bad and in my little experience not friendly to work with. Would assume most of the problems I have are easily solved if one knows how to properly use the package, however then it just goes back to me not really being able to find many tutorials, explanations, or examples of how to use the package.
  If anyone is curious here is my likely bad example of using SharpDX to generate 4 numbers 0,1,2,3, and multiplying them by 4 in a shader:

  **C#**

  ```
  using System;
  using SharpDX;
  using SharpDX.Direct3D;
  using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
  using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;
  //Based on https://gist.github.com/oguna/624969e732a868ec17f05694012c1b63

  namespace C_Sharp_Shader_test
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              int groupSize = 2; //Needs to match what is written in the shader
              int totalSize = 4; //Needs to be a multiple of groupSize, or else the shader will try to either change part of the array past its length, or not change the last parts of the array
              int elementByteSize = 4; //The size of a single element of the input-data in bytes (An int is made of 4 bytes)
              //Create device
              Device device = new Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.SingleThreaded);
              //Create compute shader
              CompilationResult bytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("Shader.hlsl", "CSMain", "cs_5_0"); //(Gotta have the shader-file Shader.hlsl be copied to the output directory for this to work)
              ComputeShader cs = new ComputeShader(device, bytecode);
              bytecode.Dispose();
              //Create input data (0,1,2,3)
              int[] inputData = new int[totalSize];
              for (int i = 0; i < inputData.Length; i++)
              {
                  inputData[i] = i;
              }
              for (int i = 0; i < inputData.Length; i++)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(inputData[i]);
              }
              Console.WriteLine("");
              //Create input buffer that has the input data
              BufferDescription inputDesc = new BufferDescription()
              {
                  SizeInBytes = elementByteSize * totalSize, //Size of the buffer in bytes
                  Usage = ResourceUsage.Default, //Lets the buffer be both written and read by the GPU
                  BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource | BindFlags.UnorderedAccess,
                  OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.BufferStructured,
                  StructureByteStride = elementByteSize, //The size of each element in bytes
                  CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read //Lets the CPU read this buffer
              };
              SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer buffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(device, inputData, inputDesc);
              //Create resource view (Seems to just be needed for the buffer)
              ShaderResourceViewDescription srvDesc = new ShaderResourceViewDescription()
              {
                  Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.Unknown,
                  Dimension = ShaderResourceViewDimension.Buffer,
                  Buffer = new ShaderResourceViewDescription.BufferResource()
                  {
                      ElementWidth = elementByteSize
                  }
              };
              ShaderResourceView srvs = new ShaderResourceView(device, buffer, srvDesc);
              //Create access view (Seems to just be needed for the buffer)
              UnorderedAccessViewDescription uavDesc = new UnorderedAccessViewDescription()
              {
                  Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.Unknown,
                  Dimension = UnorderedAccessViewDimension.Buffer,
                  Buffer = new UnorderedAccessViewDescription.BufferResource()
                  {
                      ElementCount = totalSize
                  }
              };
              UnorderedAccessView uavs = new UnorderedAccessView(device, buffer, uavDesc);
              //Set up shader
              DeviceContext context = device.ImmediateContext;
              context.ComputeShader.Set(cs);
              //Set up shader's buffer
              context.ComputeShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, buffer);
              context.ComputeShader.SetShaderResource(0, srvs);
              context.ComputeShader.SetUnorderedAccessView(0, uavs);
              //Execute shader
              int threadGroupCount = (totalSize + groupSize - 1) / groupSize; // +groupSize-1 to round up
              context.Dispatch(threadGroupCount, 1, 1);
              //Set an array "outputData" equal to the buffer's values
              DataStream ds;
              context.MapSubresource(buffer, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None, out ds);
              int[] outputData = ds.ReadRange<int>(4);
              //Dispose stuff
              context.ClearState();
              Utilities.Dispose(ref srvs);
              Utilities.Dispose(ref uavs);
              Utilities.Dispose(ref buffer);
              Utilities.Dispose(ref cs);
              Utilities.Dispose(ref device);
              //Print values
              for (int i = 0; i < outputData.Length; i++)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(outputData[i]);
              }
              //Wait so it doesn't close the console immediately.
              Console.ReadKey();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  **HLSL**

  ```
  RWStructuredBuffer<int> Result;

  [numthreads(2, 1, 1)]
  void CSMain(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
  {
      Result[id.x] = Result[id.x] * 4;
  }
  ```

  **Output:**

  > 0
  > 1
  > 2
  > 3
  >
  > 0
  > 4
  > 8
  > 12

Comment: The Compute Sharp package will only work on windows with .net Core >= version 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example (not optimized, just POC) for use of compute in DirextX through SharpDX.
An actual shader should be similar...

A very good source (imo) about programming with DirectX and HLSL (including Compute) is ['Introduction to 3D Game programming withd DirectX'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1942270062) (Frank D. Luna, isbn 978-1-942270-06-5)

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Buffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer;

namespace GpGpuDemo.Backend

{
  public class DirectComputeCalculatorWithReadBackSharpDx : IParallelCalculator
  {
    public string Description => "GPU-accelerated via SharpDX/DirectCompute (with readback) ";

    public unsafe void Calculate(float[] arrayA, float[] arrayB, float[] arrayC, Action<string> Report)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        int count = arrayA.Length;

        var device = new Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None);

        const int warpsize = 128;
        string DCShaderSource = @"
        
            StructuredBuffer<float> a;
            StructuredBuffer<float> b;
            RWStructuredBuffer<float> c;
            [numthreads(" + warpsize.ToString() + @",1,1)]
            void VectorAdd(uint3 threadId : SV_DispatchThreadID)
            {
                    uint index = threadId.x;
                    c[index] = a[index] * b[index]+a[index];                                          
            }
        ";

        // Compile the shader.
        var computeShaderCode = ShaderBytecode.Compile(DCShaderSource, "VectorAdd", "cs_5_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
        var computeShader = new ComputeShader(device, computeShaderCode);
        device.ImmediateContext.ComputeShader.Set(computeShader);

        // description for input buffers
        var inputBufferDescription = new BufferDescription
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.BufferStructured,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write,
            SizeInBytes = count * sizeof(float),
            StructureByteStride = sizeof(float)
        };


        // Description for the output buffer itself, and the view required to bind it to the pipeline.
        var outputBufferDescription = new BufferDescription
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.UnorderedAccess,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.BufferStructured,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            SizeInBytes = count * sizeof(float),
            StructureByteStride = sizeof(float)
        };



        var stagingBufferDescription = new BufferDescription
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.BufferStructured,
            SizeInBytes = count * sizeof(float),
            StructureByteStride = sizeof(float),
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
        };

        var stagingBuffer = new Buffer(device, stagingBufferDescription);
        var outputBuffer = new Buffer(device, outputBufferDescription);

        var outputViewDescription = new UnorderedAccessViewDescription
        {
            Buffer = new UnorderedAccessViewDescription.BufferResource() { FirstElement = 0, Flags = UnorderedAccessViewBufferFlags.None, ElementCount = count },

            Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.Unknown,
            Dimension = UnorderedAccessViewDimension.Buffer
        };
        var outputView = new UnorderedAccessView(device, outputBuffer, outputViewDescription);


        float[] DCArrC = new float[count];

        // prepare input buffers

        DataStream dsA;
        fixed (float* aAddress = arrayA)
        {
            dsA = new DataStream((IntPtr)aAddress, System.Buffer.ByteLength(arrayA), true, false);
        }
        var ArrayA = new Buffer(device, dsA, inputBufferDescription);
        var ArrayAView = new ShaderResourceView(device, ArrayA);

        DataStream dsB;
        fixed (float* bAddress = arrayB)
        {
            dsB = new DataStream((IntPtr)bAddress, System.Buffer.ByteLength(arrayB), true, false);
        }
        var ArrayB = new Buffer(device, dsB, inputBufferDescription);
        var ArrayBView = new ShaderResourceView(device, ArrayB);

        DataBox output;
        device.ImmediateContext.ComputeShader.SetUnorderedAccessView(0, outputView);
        device.ImmediateContext.ComputeShader.SetShaderResource(0, ArrayAView);
        device.ImmediateContext.ComputeShader.SetShaderResource(1, ArrayBView);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            sw.Restart();
            for (int teller = 0; teller < 10; teller++)
            {
                device.ImmediateContext.Dispatch(count / warpsize, 1, 1);
            }
            device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(outputBuffer, stagingBuffer);
            DataStream result;
            output = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(stagingBuffer, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None, out result);
            fixed (float* cAddress = arrayC)
            {
                result.Read((IntPtr)cAddress, 0, System.Buffer.ByteLength(arrayC));
            }
            device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(stagingBuffer, 0);
            sw.Stop();
            var s = sw.Elapsed;

            Report($"Operation finished in {s.Minutes} minutes, {s.Seconds} seconds, {s.Milliseconds} milliseconds");
        }
        ArrayA.Dispose();
        ArrayB.Dispose();
        dsA.Dispose();
        dsB.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

You can [mail me](http://mailto://johan.donne@odisee.be) for a complete working solution, comparing execution on the CPU (single threaded and multithreaded, in OpenCL & DirectCompute)