# Fastest conditional count algorithm

Tags: c#

Consider the table below. It has 400,000 rows with 40 columns with values which can range from 0 to 4,000.

| MeasureValue1 | MeasureValue2 | MeasureValue3 | ... | MeasureValue40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 7 | ... | 2740 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 | ... | 2749 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | ... | 2703 |
| 4 | 6 | 8 | ... | 2721 |

Conditions are then given per column to which other columns in the row must suffice before the value in that specific column is counted, these conditions are only known at runtime. Essentially a group by is performed across every column where other columns in the row satisfy the given conditions. For example, these conditions could be as follows.

- Count MeasureValue1 if MeasureValue2 equals 5
- Count MeasureValue2 if MeasureValue1 equals 2
- Count MeasureValue3 if MeasureValue1 equals 2 and MeasureValue2 equals 5
- ...
- Count MeasureValue40 if MeasureValue1 equals 2 and MeasureValue2 equals 5

In which the final result would be a table with counts per value. Given the example conditions above, that table would look as follows.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | ... | 2749 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1 |

To tackle this problem I have written something akin to the code below. It is definitely faster than performing a LINQ GroupBy across every column, and also faster even compared to multithreaded LINQ. It takes in an array of 400,000 times 40 values. You can imagine the 40 values as being a single row in a table as described above, of which there are 400,000 rows with those 40 values. Those 40 values can range from 0 to 4,000.

Since both the amount of rows and the amount of values can change dynamically, a single array was chosen to store everything. The reason jagged arrays are not being used is due to being clunky to work with, on top of having read that they negatively affect performance.

The code then counts the values present in the array if any combination of the 39 values meets a specific condition. In the example below the first value is counted if the second value is a 5, the second value is counted if the first value is a 2, and the third value is counted if the first value is a 2 and the second value is a 5. These conditions are only known at runtime. The combinations of conditions each with their own range of hundreds of possible values quickly reaches an array with a length too big to store, which means I cannot bake the amounts in some array and be done with it.

This piece of code will be called billions of times per day, maybe more, so it is imperative that it is as quick as possible. The implementation I have currently, which resembles the example below (there is an additional optimization which only counts the conditions once), has it down to an average of 40 milliseconds, I need to reduce this to at least 4 milliseconds by any means possible (except parallelism, obviously throwing more cores at it will make it faster). I briefly looked at [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) but couldn't figure out how to apply it to this problem. How/where can I find the fastest algorithm to tackle this problem?

```
void Main()
{
    var values = new ushort[400_000 * 40];

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    
    var totals = new ushort[4_000];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 40)
    {
        if (values[i + 1] == 5)
        {
            totals[values[i]]++;
        }

        if (values[i] == 2)
        {
            totals[values[i + 1]]++;
        }

        if (values[i] == 2 && values[i + 1] == 5)
        {
            totals[values[i + 2]]++;
        }
        
        // More ifs which count...
    }

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: So you have 400k samples and you want to iterate 1000 times ? Have you considered doing the inner loop with generated, native C-code on a <Span> defined in C# ? Have you considered to use a *sample* of 400k samples  and store you output in a seperate buffer ? An array of 16M samples easily runs out of cache, while 400k samples (without the +40 step) may run smoothly.

Comment: @Goodies I beg your pardon sir, the 1000 iterations were merely to have a clearer average picture on performance.

Comment: You can't speed up that code by much, and that code already suffers from the fact that it is static, not dynamic. You could try to reorder memory accesses, so that you do all the checks with values[i] before doing the checks to values[i + 1]. This would help a little the cache. Sadly there are too few registers in x64 processors to simply load a "batch" of 40 values in the registers. (in the example given you would do the 2nd and the 3rd check before the 1st). Still hinting a little putting all the 40 values in 40 local variables and using them could be better (v0=values[i], v1=values[i + 1])

Comment: @bdebaere you were very fast.. I finished my comment..

Comment: @Goodies I have considered nothing of the sort, because I don't know what my options are, which is the very reason for this post: to know my options. Do you have any links I can read concerning your points?

Comment: I hope you are doing the tests in Release Mode without a debugger attached (CTRL+F5 in Visual Studio), the difference in speed is very big

Comment: @xanatos Yes I am testing in release mode without a debugger attached. Can you clarify further what you mean by "that code already suffers from the fact that it is static, not dynamic"?

Comment: Ignore the second tip, your values are dependent on buffer[i+1] values so you can't avoid the +xx array size. I would consider using unmanaged, *generated* C-code for this, which has also the advantage you won't have to rewrite things in C# when you change conditions. The <Span> is a way to marshall a buffer to non-managed code, allowing native C to look into your buffer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/january/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay

Comment: @bdebaere _These conditions are only known at runtime_ But your code is _static_. You'll need _dynamic_ code to do what you want. For example autogenerated with Roslyn, or with a compiled Expression tree. Both solutions slow a little the execution.

Comment: @xanatos Yes, indeed, the example code is indeed not dynamic. I tried to keep to the essentials only, which is why I didn't include it.

Comment: @Goodies I'll check if native C gives a substantial performance increase.

Comment: Other than using 40 local variables, I would say that jagged arrays could be faster. With your array accessing a location in the array requires two sums: address of vales plus i plus x (0, 1, 2, ...40), while with a jagged array, after storing the base address of the row in a variable, you would have address of row plus x (0, 1, 2, ...40)

Comment: @xanatos Ok, I will take a look into jagged arrays also.

Comment: This benchmark does not actually measure the cost of the code.  Add  `for (int ix = 0; ix < values.Length; ix++) values[ix] = 0;`  before starting the stopwatch, ensuring the array is initialized as will happen in the real program.  Now you're no longer measuring the paging cost and it executes in well less than 4 msec.

Comment: @HansPassant As far as I'm aware, arrays in C# are initialised with 0 values by default. While it is true that the code in the ifs is never executed, and thus this is not a real benchmark, it was never the intention, merely to display the code I have.

Comment: I do not think there is any easy way to use SIMD here. But parallelizing should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: What about a DX-11 compute shader.. use the GPU for this ? (sunglasses smiley) you could use SharpDX, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63281715/how-to-execute-hlsl-from-c